# How to pass a javascript variable in a PHP url??

Tags: javascript, php

I would like to redirect to the chosen page after having validated the form.
I started this:

```
<form action = "planning.php?court= variable" method = "POST">.

<script>
        function courtNumber () {
            var variable = document.getElementById ("tennis_court"). value;
            alert (variable);
        }
</script>
```

I catch the correct value in my alert when I click on validate, now I would like to insert it in my  tag.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reassign the action of the form.

```
function courtNumber () {
    var variable = document.getElementById("tennis_court").value;
    document.querySelector("form").action = "planning.php?court=" + encodeURIComponent(variable);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped `variable` as `value`

Comment: thank you, I did it and I replaced my code with yours but still no "planning?court = variable" in my url, variable is always null.

Comment: How are you calling `courtNumber()`?

Comment: In my input of the form: <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Valider" onclick="courtnumber()">

Comment: it's ok, I saw the mistake when I post you the last message, it's courtNumber and no courtnumber, thank you very much, it's ok!

Comment: Didn't you see the error in the console before you posted?

Answer (score 0):

First you can add one id to your form, so you can access it in your function.

```
<form action = "planning.php?court= variable" method = "POST" id="myForm">
</form>
```

Then, in your script you can acces the action property and set the value there.

```
<script>
function courtNumber () 
    {
        var variable = document.getElementById("tennis_court").value;
        alert (variable);

        document.getElementById("myForm").action = "planning.php?court=" + variable;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You're missing the `planning.php` part of the action in your assignment.